# BASH script: Reading from 1-line file into multiple global variables

Tags: bash, sed, global-variables

I have been struggling in bash to parse and read a parameter file into multiple gobal variables.  We run both HPUX and Linux environments, and I'm trying to get this working in BASH.  It is currently giving me error on the sed statement.  Even when I take out the sed, inside the loop it reads the variable(s), but it the values revert to the global definition as soon as I'm out of the loop.  Have tried adding "#!/bin/sh" at top of file, but that doesn't work like borne shell, the commented code is borne shell from the HPUX system.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
set -xv

ReadStat() {
set -xv

while read EngName AllTabs Distribs DropDist BlockSet BlockExp BlockBy MaxProcs ; do
   echo "read: EngName=$EngName AllTabs=$AllTabs Distribs=$Distribs DropDist=$DropDist BlockSet=$BlockSet BlockExp=$BlockExp BlockBy=$BlockBy MaxProcs=$MaxProcs "
done < sed -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/|/ /g" $StatFile 

#cat $StatFile |\
#  sed -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" |\
#  sed -e "s/|/ /g" |\
#  read EngName AllTabs Distribs DropDist BlockSet BlockExp BlockBy MaxProcs

}

# main() {


BaseNameIs=`basename $0 '.sh'`

StatFile=/tmp/kz.stat

EngName="it1xxx"
CronJob='Y'
Distribs='B'
DropDist='N'
AllTabs='N'
BlockSet='N'
# BlockExp=`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`
BlockExp=`date '+%Y%m%d'`'0000'
BlockBy='none'
MaxProcs=30

MyHost=`hostname`

ReadStat 

# main() }
```

Input file looks like:

```
it1xxx|Y|B|N|Y|201401071110|none|30|
```

Comment: Any chance you'd like to skip BASH and use Perl?  A `split` would do wonders on a one-liner like that... `my ($EngName,$CronJob,$Distribs,$DropDist,$AllTabs,$BlockSet,$BlockExp,$BlockBy,$MaxProcs,$MyHost)=split('|', $lineIn); $MyHost=defined($MyHost)?$MyHost:\`hostname\``...

Comment: Aren't he first 3 `-e`s in your `sed -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/||/|-|/g" -e "s/|/ /g" $StatFile` duplicates? you only need 1 of those because you're using the 'g'. Oh, and of course feeding `sed ..` into a redirect (`<`), would require process substitution, ie. `while ... ; done <(sed ....)` or maybe `< <(sed ...)`. OR move the sed to feed the while thru a pipe at the front, `sed ... | while ...` Good luck.

Comment: actually, those are present in case the file has no values.  Even with the global, ||| will only be fixed by the first substitute, the second substitute will catch the second immediate occurance.  The third is probably redundant.

Comment: PERL would be interesting, but we have a huge library of borne shells...  I'd have to write some kind of translation utility (which I may have to do for bash anyway.... )

Answer (score 5):

The bash `read` command can handle this:

```
vars="EngName AllTabs Distribs DropDist BlockSet BlockExp BlockBy MaxProcs"
IFS='|' read -r $vars dummy < kz.stat
for var in $vars; do echo "$var = ${!var}"; done
```

```
EngName = it1xxx
AllTabs = Y
Distribs = B
DropDist = N
BlockSet = Y
BlockExp = 201401071110
BlockBy = none
MaxProcs = 30
```

It's crucial to **not** quote `$vars` in both the read and for commands.

Comment: nice. Totaly forgot about the IFS trick today. You need to eval instead of echo to set the variables for further use though.

Comment: No need for eval anywhere. The echo is simply to demonstrate that the variables have been set correctly by the read command.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that while loops generally run in their own sub-shell.   Probably the most straightforward solution is to save the output into a temporary file and then source the temporary file.

Here's a web page that illustrates some solutions.
[fvue.nl wiki page](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash%3a_Piped_%60while-read%27_loop_starts_subshell)